# I'm having a small IT issue

Tags: cookies, asterisk, brackets

I was recently doing some work on my browser and looking at my cookies. In the url it listed it was written as https://www.examplesite[*.].com/

what are the brackets and asterisk for? I've never run across that before. would appreciate any help I could

Answer (score -1):

Matt, sometimes programmers when they are setting up their code put in strings that they intend to come back to and expand, but never get around to doing it. The code or comment passes the normal checks and ends up in your log files or cookies or whatever. In this case the programmer evidently has a domain with a number of subdomains or the same subdomain on a number of different domains and intends to use the same code for each. It is lazy programming, but might make some sense if there are many subdomains to consider and they cannot find the time to programme a way to be more explicit, relying on the pattern to make sense to anyone that needs to read it.

It might also have been generated by your browser (which one are you using?) - although scanning through my cookie list in FF I see linkedin.com has left cookies from subdomains uk. and ca. for me so evidently FF does not try to reduce the length of the list in this way.